# FileName hidden/mysterious property

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, filenames, hidden

today while writing a simple app to put music to folders based on their artist and album I came across something that surprised me.

Just to display files to my information I used ListView:

```
    <Grid Margin="10" MaxHeight="300">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MusicList}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="File Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileName}" Width="250"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Artist" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TagHandler.Artist}" Width="150"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Album" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TagHandler.Album}" Width="150"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TagHandler.Title}" Width="200"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

MusicList is an array created with help of library "Mp3Lib" and it goes like this

```
    public Mp3Lib.Mp3File[] MusicList
    {
        get { return musicList; }
        private set
        {
            musicList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MusicList");
        }
    }
    private Mp3Lib.Mp3File[] musicList;
```

List view itself is binded to MusicList while Artist, Album and Title are binded to TagHandler.Artist and so on. TagHandler comes directly from MusicList and that makes absolute sense.

Question that I have is about this FileName. To be honest with you I just placed it there by a chance, was going to create some property with that name or whatever but I didn't. When I started program I was amazed to see that the column was filled with complete file directory with a name like this:

[image]

What I don't know is that where that FileName property comes from, are there any similar properties out there that I could use? Once again I want to say that I have no property of this name neither MusicList has.

If anyone knows something about this I would be grateful for information.

Comment: Please do not use links to external resources to support your question. Stack Overflow questions should be entirely self-contained, to ensure against becoming out-of-date if and when external resources change or are removed completely. Please *do* provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I did delete the link. Note that it wasn't essential part of a question but just an addition for people who wanted to go deeper. Since I didn't know where in a code answer could be I decided to provide link to it. Nevertheless I removed link just not break the rules of this site.

Comment: Links are not prohibited...it's just that the question can't _rely_ on them. Personally, I feel that your question does not have enough information in it -- the binding to the `Mp3Lib.Mp3File` type depends on the declaration of that type, but your question doesn't show that type -- but others may feel differently. My point wasn't that you should remove the link, but that you _should_ improve the question by providing important, missing details.

Answer (score 2):

`FileName` is a property of `Mp3Lib.Mp3File` not `MusicList`, those bindings are not to the collection but to properties of line items in the collection.

Comment: Thank you very much, I feel really stupid right now... I went through all those properties when relating to MusicList and there was nothing but when I call for example MusicList[0] it is in fact in there. Thank you once again and sorry for bothering. Maybe one additional question to this one if you don't mind. What is the fastest/simplest way of editing this FileName to display let's say just name of the file without directory? I was thinking of creating additional class and there using it but that seems like a lot of work for such a menial task. Once again thank you for help.